# Why would this theorem be false if subharmonic functions were continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have read that this theorem would be untrue if subharmonic were continuous instead of just upper semicontinuous. Why is that?

> **Theorem** Let $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be subharmonic functions on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose $u_1 \geq u_2 \geq \cdots$ on $U$. Then $u:=\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n$ is subharmonic on U.

Thanks!

Comment: In other words: Even if we additionally assume that the $u_n$ are continuous, we cannot expect the limit $u$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Because this limit is non necessarily continuous, even when $u_n$ are continuous subharmonic functions. For example, let $U$ be the unit disk, and
$$u_n(z)=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\log|z-1/k|.$$
The limit $u$ exists and is finite at $0$. 
But it equals $-\infty$ at all points $1/k$.

If you do not want to call $\log|z|$ continuous, replace it by by
$\max\{\log|z|,-M\}$, where $M>0$ is a large number (larger than $|u(0)|$)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! When you work on the extended line, you would call $\log|z|$ continuous, right? But anyhow $max\{\log|z|,-M\}|$ is not continuous, so I’m not sure I’m getting the last part of what you wrote?

Comment: $\max\{ \log|z|,-M\}$ is continuous, maximum of two continuous functions is continuous. I do not understand your confusion.

Comment: I’m sorry, I meant that if you say that $\log|z|$ is not continuous, then you are not taking the maximum of two continuous functions because you just said $\log|z|$ wasn’t continuous?

Comment: Why don't you draw the graph of $\max\{\log|x|,-M\}$ instead of asking such questions?